# How to dynamically set Test mode for a Webform_CiviCRM Contribution using Stripe Payment Processor

Tags: webforms, civicrm

This is in Drupal 9.5, CiviCRM 5.60, Webform 6.1, Webform_CiviCRM 6.2.

I have a webform which is allowing a Contact to make a CiviCRM Contribution - for example a simple Donation.  If I manually set the Contribution into Test mode, then I can perform the payment process with a test card number, without actual money being involved.  I would like to be able to programmatically set Test mode during the process, so that a particular Test User can make Test transactions while any other user is making live ones.

I can use `hook_form_alter()` to set 'is_test' and alter the Payment Processor to the test Id rather than the live one.

[image]

[image]

However, using `hook_civicrm_alterPaymentProcessorParams()` I can see that this has not propagated to the Payment Processor details.  I can then alter the Payment Processor Id and 'is_test' in the `rawParams` array and also add these to `cookedParams`.  (One cannot usefully alter the `paymentObj` parameter since it is not passed to the hook by reference.)

[image]

[image]

If I do all of these actions then the Test card number is accepted, and Stripe says *'Wait while we pre-authorise your card'*, but then gives an error saying:

> No such payment_intent: 'pi_3N5W6IAQCXrpfr1t3tXQRdVm'; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request.

I can also see that the paymentObj parameter contains the live PP Id, 'is_test' set to zero, and the live keys rather than test ones, which is clearly why it throws the error.

[image]

Is there any way of intervening earlier in the process so that live mode can be altered to test mode, and have that propagate into the Payment Processor details?

Comment: if you've not done so already you might get a better response posting this question in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com